# Developing app solo with sensitive information

Tags: git, android-studio, security, svn, version-control

I'm making myself an app with Android Studio. It will have sensitive information (like social security number etc.) and I don't have any private repos on sites like Github. What is the best option for version control? I will be the only developer.

Can Git and SVN be setup to use the local computer or do they need a remote server? Would it make sense even considering Git as it seems like the main advantage is the ability to push once back online?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Git for version control, below are the options for you to manage your git repo privately.

#### Option 1: Hosted  remote repo to 3rd-party companies where private git repos are free

For Github, you need additional pays to use priavte git repos. While, you can hosted your remote git repo to other place where the private git repos are free. Such as you can use [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/product?_mid=d33f5a6c95e8e3f161faec8838a6151f&utm_content=bb_dstest-google_portfolio-cpa_port1&aceid=&adposition=1t1&adgroup=9753931967&campaign=177596927&creative=226329906718&device=c&keyword=bitbucket&matchtype=e&network=g&placement=&ds_kids=p19174193953&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI292Y35-x2gIVhgoqCh1y8wldEAAYASAAEgJsXfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) instead. You can select to create private/public repo freely.

#### Option 2: Setup remote repo by yourself

You can setup your own remote repo by `git into --bare`, and then push the changes to your own remote repo. And if you have server(s), you can setup the git repo there, so that only the people who can access to your server have permission to access your git repo.

Comment: Is putting sensitive information on bitbucket, even with a private repo, still safe? Couldn't staff who work there look at the data or is it stored encrypted?

Comment: Bitbucket private repo is safe. But if you add a user with access permission, the user can get the source file (without encrypted). And the workaround for the sensitive information which you do not want anyone to access, you can manage the information in another repo separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Subversion locally without any server. Subversion client can access the repository via `file://` access schema.

This approach should work in case there is only one or a couple of users who plan to use the repository. It will be simple to move the repository to a cloud or on-premise SVN server.

Answer (score -1):

Well, svn has to have a server process to connect to.  I guess it's up to you whether that is hosted on a remote computer, or on your desktop.

By contrast, git doesn't require a server of any sort.  Its functionality is completely local.  It does define protocols for sharing objects (i.e. your history, more or less) with other repos if you want, and those repos can be on a remote computer if you want, but all actual source control functions are local.

So while git's design is motivated by the need for ludicrously distributed development on a project like the Linux kernel, it's also a perfectly sensible option when you just want to work locally (with the caveat that if there's only one local copy of the repo database, then you're data is only as protected as the backups you keep of your local system).

Not sure what leads you to think that the ability to work in isolation and then sync up with a remote later is the "main" advantage of git.

Comment: This is **not** true: `Well, svn has to have a server process to connect to.`